# Hyperlinking for image

Tags: javascript, image, dom, hyperlink

I am using JavaScript to specify the target link. It is not working properly. What change should I do in order for it to work correctly?

My code:

```
var link = create_element(cell, 'img');
link.setAttribute("src", "images/sub.png"); 
link.href = "http://localhost/";
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As Sergei stated, you need a link with an image inside it.
Below is an extension to your code. It's completely untested though but gives a general idea on how you might achieve it based on what you had already.

```
var link = create_element(cell, 'a');
link.href = "http://localhost/";
var image = create_element(link, 'img');
image.setAttribute("src", "images/sub.png");
```

Answer (score 5):

You can't use href for an img tag. What about adding a clickhandler?

```
link.onclick = function(){top.location.replace("http://localhost");};
```

Answer (score 4):

IMG tag doesn't have href attribute. "A" tag has it. So you should create A with desired HREF, then IMG inside.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, exactly. We can also write:

```
link.onclick = function() { document.location.href = "http://localhost"; };
```